# Python mock func of an obj

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

Hello my name is UserName and I can't mock =(

I have next code:

**app/worker/dataObj.py**

```
class DataObj:

    def __init__(self, data: dict):
        if 'assignee' in data:
            self.users = self.get_users()
            print(self.users)    

    def get_users(self):
        users = requests.get(url=URL, headers=HEADERS)
        return json.loads(users.text)
```

**app/test/test_dataObj.py**

```
import unittest
from app.worker.dataObj import DataObj
app.test.test_data import test_data
unittest.mock import patch


TestDataObj(unittest.TestCase):

    setUp(self):
        data = test_data.data_for_dataobj
        dataobj = DataObj(self.data)

    @patch.object(DataObj, 'get_users')
    test_dataobj(self, gu):
        gu.return_value = {'user1': 111, 'User2': 222}
        print(gu)
        self.assertEqual(self.dataobj.tags, ["11", "22", "401", "88888"])
```

I also try to path like this:

```
@patch("app.worker.dataObj.requests.get")
@patch("app.worker.dataObj.DataObj.get_users")
```

but it still doesn't mock

I've read different related questions here, and it seems as a path issue, but can't figured out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I stop trying to test realisation instead I start to test interface.

```
@patch("app.worker.dataObj.requests.get")
def test_dataobj_assignee(self, mock_req):
    mock_req.return_value.text = json.dumps(test_data.get_users_return)
    self.dataobj = DataObj(self.test_data.assignee)
    self.assertEqual(self.dataobj.assignee, 1130000021382371)
```

Hopefully it will helpful for somebody.